# Making a Point Class in Python

Tags: python, class, function, methods, point

I am trying to create a class in python titled "Point." I am trying to create a point on a coordinate plane x and y and track them. As well as find the distance between the points. I have to use functions and methods. I have started and here is my code. I am just not sure how to use it when I go to execute the program. Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT: Updated Code

```
import math


class Point(object):
    '''Creates a point on a coordinate plane with values x and y.'''

    COUNT = 0

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        '''Defines x and y variables'''
        self.X = x
        self.Y = y

    def move(self, dx, dy):
        '''Determines where x and y move'''
        self.X = self.X + dx
        self.Y = self.Y + dy

    def __str__(self):
        return "Point(%s,%s)"%(self.X, self.Y) 


    def getX(self):
        return self.X

    def getY(self):
        return self.Y

    def distance(self, other):
        dx = self.X - other.X
        dy = self.Y - other.Y
        return math.sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2)

    def testPoint(x=0,y=0):
        '''Returns a point and distance'''
        p1 = Point(3, 4)
        print p1
        p2 = Point(3,0)
        print p2
        return math.hypot(dx, dy)

    print "distance = %s"%(testPoint())
```

I still need help understanding how to actually use the code. That's why I created the `testPoint` function. When I actually go to execute the code in IDLE, how do I prove that everything works? Thanks a bunch guys!!

I also need to add code to the constructor to increment `COUNT` by 1 every time a Point object is created. I also need to add appropriate code so that points can be compared using the comparison operators while 'points' are compared based on their distance from the origin.

Comment: don't write getters in python unless/until you have to make attributes into properties for whatever reason.

Comment: i would create x and y functions and use them as properties as shapely does it.

Answer (score 7):

Don't forget `math.hypot`

```
def distance(self, p):
    dx = self.X - p.X
    dy = self.Y - p.Y
    return hypot(dx, dy)
```

Answer (score 4):

- You declared `distance` as taking an argument `p`; inside the method you're referring to it as `other`. Change `p` to `other` in the declaration so they match.
- `sqrt()` isn't a builtin; you need to do `import math` and refer to it as `math.sqrt()`.
- You aren't doing anything with the `testPoint()` function you declare; you can invoke it by adding a line at the end like:

`print "distance = %s"%(testPoint())`

At that point, your code works and computes a distance of 4.0 between your points.

Now, some style issues:

- In Python, you don't generally privatize member variables, and you don't bother writing trivial getters and setters, so you can remove the `getX()` and `getY()` methods and just refer to `p.X` and `p.Y` directly given a `Point p`.
- The `math` module has a convenient hypotenuse function, so in `distance()` you can change the return line to `return math.hypot(dx,dy)`.
- By default, a user defined object has an unattractive string representation:

  `<__main__.Point object at 0x1004e4550>`

You should define a string conversion method in your class like so:

```
    def __str__(self):
        return "Point(%s,%s)"%(self.X,self.Y)
```

This will be used when the object is printed, or otherwise needs to be converted to a string.

Comment: Thank you sir! Very helpful and thorough. I have applied these changes. I also need to add code to the constructor to increment COUNT by 1 every time a Point object is created. I also need to add appropriate code so that points can be compared using the comparison operators while points are compared based on their distance from the origin. Finally, I still need help understanding how to execute all this code. Thats what the testPoint function is for.

Comment: Seems like you've got a handle on it. `p1.move( 2, 7 )` moves `p1` from its current position to (5, 11). `p2.Y` is 0. Define the comparison operators described here: http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__ to compare points by distance from origin (though you can probably get away with just defining `__cmp__()`).

Comment: Where would I implement the p1.move and stuff. Is p1 a variable? Thats the part I am confused on

Answer (score 3):

Hum, why not use complex instead of a point class? 
It has all the properties you are searching for and more (such as rotation).

Here is an example to "OOP" the complex with a pedantic notation:

https://gist.github.com/jul/9286835

Answer (score 1):

In your Point.distance method, you reference other.X and other.Y; Other does not exists.

You should either change the distance signature to be distance(self, other) or change the code to use p.

You will also need to import math.sqrt:

```
from math import sqrt
```