# cannot unpack non-iterable int object for given recurrence relationship for two coupled sequences?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recurrence

I have created the code for recurrence relationship for two coupled sequences but for some reason, I'm getting an error

**Code:**

```
import math

for x,y in range(1,3):
    def Function_X_Y(x,y):
        x_val = (-5*x*(n-2)) + (2*y*(n-1))
        y_val = (3*y*(n-2)) - (4*x*(n-1)) + (4*y*(n-1)) 
        return(x_val, y_val)

def coupled_sequence(n):
    return Function_X_Y(x,y)

print(coupled_sequence(0))
print(coupled_sequence(1))
print(coupled_sequence(5))

#Expected output: print(coupled_sequence(0))
#>>> (1, 1)

#print(coupled_sequence(1))
#>>> (2, 2)

#print(coupled_sequence(5))
#>>> (246, 322)
```

**Error**

```
----> 5 for x,y in range(1,3):
      6     def Function_X_Y(x,y):
      7         x_val = (-5*x*(n-2)) + (2*y*(n-1))

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

I have tried different ways to iterate over the given function with the help of `for` loop, but can't get the expected output

Comment: What specifically are you trying to do? Are you just trying to set `x=1` and `y=2`? It's not clear why you'd need a for loop to do that. And for that matter, `n` is undefined in `Function_X_Y`; I assume you're intending that to be passed in as a variable? Please clarify

Comment: I'm trying to set `x=y =1,2` can you help me how to define n as well ? and Yeah, I'm trying to pass it as a variable.  `xn=−5xn−2+2yn−1` and `yn=3yn−2−4xn−1+4yn−1` where `x,y = 1, 2` I'm trying to iterate over the for loop to get the result from calling function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) as it is being used will only return one integer each iteration, so you cannot get multiple values that way. Depending on your use case you could just create another loop inside the one you have, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18817207/use-python-to-create-2d-coordinate).