# Simplification of if multiple conditions in python

Tags: python, if-statement

I want to pick out some items in one rectangular box with axis limits of (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, zmin, zmax). So i use the following conditions,

```
if not ((xi >= xmin and xi <= xmax) and (yi >= ymin and yi <= ymax) and (zi >= zmin and zi <= zmax)):
    expression
```

But I think python has some concise way to express it. Does anyone can tell me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Typical case for [*operator chaining*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons):

```
if not (xmin <= xi <= xmax and ymin <= yi <= ymax and zmin <= zi <= zmax):
```

Not only it simplifies the comparisons, allowing to remove parentheses, while retaining readability, but also the center argument is only evaluated *once* , which is particularly interesting when comparing against the result of a function:

```
if xmin <= func(z) <= xmax:
```

(so it's not equivalent to 2 comparisons if `func` has a side effect)

Comment: [Associated documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons)

Comment: @Gao If their answer satisfies your question, please mark it as such with the green checkmark.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 thanks. Was trying to get an internal bookmark on that page :)

Comment: Just wondering how that is valid. `xmin <= xi` returns True, which is evaluated as `1` and then it shouldn't make sense, but surprisingly, it works perfectly fine

Comment: @Ayxan Comparison operators don't associate in this case; `x <= y <= z` is evaluated like `x <= y and y <= z` (but with `y` evaluated only once). It doesn't simply evaluate `x <= y` and then compare the result to `z`.

Comment: @chepner that's really interesting. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: if you do `(x <= y) <= z`, then you get your nasty boolean effect you were (?) looking for

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to start cooking with gas, create a class library for handling 3D points (e.g. by extending this one to include the Z coordinate: [Making a Point Class in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468900/making-a-point-class-in-python)).

You could then encapsulate the above solution into a method of the class, as:

```
def isInBox(self, p1, p2):
    return (p1.X <= self.X <= p2.X and p1.Y <= self.Y <= p2.Y and p1.Z <= self.Z <= p2.Z)
```

Comment: Yes. I understand your idea. Thanks.